# Access github repository by a collaborator through android studio

Tags: android-studio, github, commit, collaboration

I added my friend as a collaborator to my private github repository.Now that repo is visible through my friends github repository lisy.

Now he is trying to commit source code from his android studio  to the repository that he is added as a collaborator. But studio is asking to create a new repository ; not asking to select an existing repository. even if he creates a new repository, it 'll be created inside his account. Not inside my github account.

Any idea of how to solve this issue?
Thanks in advance.